# Can I run a Qt application with a specific theme?

Tags: qt

Can I run a Qt application with a specific theme? I would like the application to use an OS theme that is different than the current OS theme.

Answer (score 21):

Yes. In `main()` before you create your instance of QApplication, you can call `QApplication::setStyle("plastique")` for example. Some of the other style strings would be: "windows", "motif", "cde", "plastique" and "cleanlooks" and depending on the platform, "windowsxp", "windowsvista" and "macintosh".

Calling the other overloaded version of this function would work too such as `QApplication::setStyle(new QWindowsXPStyle)`.

It could also be specified on the command line when launching the application using the -style switch:

```
./myapplication -style motif
```

Comment: what I mean is can I for example have my app run with the DarkRoom theme while the OS theme is human on ubuntu for example.  I am talking about the gnome desktop theme.

Comment: Well, that will teach me to look more carefully at the tags. Sorry :)

Comment: `QStyle` availablity will depend on the platform you're targeting. You can print a list of what `QStyle`s are available at run time via: `qDebug() << QStyleFactory::keys()`. Each of these strings is a theme that can be passed to `QApplication::setStyle`.

Comment: Will the command-line switch work in Windows?

Answer (score 4):

QT doc says :

```
void QApplication::setDesktopSettingsAware ( bool on ) [static]
```

> Sets whether Qt should use the system's standard colors, fonts, etc., to on. By default, this is true.This function must be called before creating the QApplication object, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication::setDesktopSettingsAware(false);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    ...
    return app.exec();
}
```

So it should work out of the box. But I noticed that when I run my application in QtSDK the system color scheme is 'not found', I mean my `QApplication`s seems not settings aware. I **deployed** some of them on a nice `ubuntu` installation and I get the rigth theme. I don't know what's under the hood though but certainly something about `$QTDIR` content ...

Comment: this explains how I would make in not aware of desktop settings but what do I do to make it use Ubuntu's Darkroom theme.

Comment: This is just to mention that it should be done automatically. If not it could be a good idea to check the deployed version of Qt your are linking to and it's integration. Does other Qt applications from the package manager use properly the current theme once installed ?

Comment: i omitted to specify that I am attempting to use an OS theme that is different than the current OS theme.  This might not be a possible task.

Comment: Ok that's should make a huge difference ... In this case you should try follows what the `settingsAware` stuffs do (I mean in the Qt sources) their you should be able to figure out how to choose your own theme (should be a folder or a file selection at the very end !)