# Building a Qt example doen't give the same output, window customizing

Tags: c++, qt

Can someone explain to me why when I build this example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html, I don't get the same output as show in that example, instead I get the default windows window style.
[image]
left as in the example, right my output

This leads to another question:

if I want to customize my window using `Qt Widget Application` to something other than the default style/design, how is that possible?

Ps: I already tried to fill the background with a color, it worked but didn't applied on the window borders.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot was taken under the KDE desktop, not Windows. No wonder it looks like KDE, while yours looks like Windows. Qt adapts to the current desktop in its default styling.

For changing the styling please refer to the relevant question here on SO:
[Can I run a Qt application with a specific theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740333/can-i-run-a-qt-application-with-a-specific-theme-on-linux)

Comment: I tried `QApplication::setStyle("macintosh");` before `QApplication a(argc, argv);` but nothing changed.