# I want Qt-app to look like Qt-app rather than Android-native

Tags: android, c++, qt

Due to removing upper bar (where clock, battery and other such things are situated) I have access to QtActivity.java.
I have tried to set

```
public String ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES = "QT_USE_ANDROID_NATIVE_DIALOGS=0";
```

but without any result.
And there is one strange thing: on the first start of the app it looks like Android-app(ugly and curvy), but on the second run it starts looking like normal Qt-app.
I want program not to use Android styles from the start.

What can I do?

P.S. I use QWidgets, no QQuick/QML

Alas, but this method doesn't work under Android: [Can I run a Qt application with a specific theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740333)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I run a Qt application with a specific theme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740333/can-i-run-a-qt-application-with-a-specific-theme)

Comment: Alas, but this method doesn't work under Android.

Comment: Some widgets can work on Android, but they are not supported and can lead to trouble.
I don't know if [setStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setStyle) works on Android, but try if you can.

Comment: Yes! I owe you a few bottles of beer! setStyle() wasn't enough by itself. There was also need in QStyleFactory!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to main()

```
QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
```

No need to edit AndroidManifest.xml or QtActivity.java